# A pdf file generated from latex code created in a wrong directory - Python

Tags: python, pdf, latex

I am currently trying to write a program which opens a latex file and generates a pdf with the same name and saves it in the same folder as the latex file. 
My problem: The pdf file is created in the same folder as the python file of the program I am running, rather than the folder where the latex file is -  I can't get my head around why this is happening. I am trying to achieve my goal in two steps. 
First I use a function which takes the directory and the title of the latex file, so that a pdf with the same name can be generated:

```
 def getName(self, somestring):                                                    

    if "/" in somestring:
        indexsofslash = [i for i, ltr in enumerate(somestring) if ltr == "/"]
        indexsofdot = [i for i, ltr in enumerate(somestring) if ltr == "."]
        lastindexslash = max(indexsofslash)
        lastindexdot = max(indexsofdot)
        mainName = somestring[lastindexslash + 1:lastindexdot]
        pdfDirectory = somestring[:lastindexslash + 1]
        someothername = pdfDirectory +  mainName
        newname = someothername
    else:
        newname = somestring 
    return newname
```

After that I use this function to generate a pdf file, using:

```
def generate_pdf(self):

    name=self.getName(self.fl)      
    f = open('%s.tex'%name,'w')
    tex = self.txt.get(1.0,"end-1c")
    f.write(tex)
    f.close()
    proc=subprocess.Popen(['pdflatex','%s.tex'%name])
    proc.communicate()
    os.startfile('%s.pdf'%name)
    #os.unlink('%s.tex'%name)
    os.unlink('%s.log'%name)
    os.unlink('%s.aux'%name)
```

*Note: when name is printed it shows the directory of the latex file + the title of the file, i.e. H:/Public/Test/test.

What happens: A pdf is generated in the folder where the python file of the program I am running is, rather than in the folder where my latex file is - what is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that by default `pdflatex` writes the output files into the current working directory. To alter that behaviour you need to supply an option.

Take a look at the `man` page of `pdflatex`:

```
$ man pdflatex
```

and search for `-output-directory`, and you will see:

> -output-directory directory
>   Write output files in directory instead of the current directory.  Look up input files in directory first, the along the normal search path.

Thus you will need to modify your python code to something like this:

```
proc=subprocess.Popen(['pdflatex', '-output-directory', pdfDirectory, '%s.tex' % name])
```

assuming `pdfDirectory` is your detination.

Comment: So I tried writing this:  proc=subprocess.Popen(['pdflatex','%s.tex'%name,'-output-directory',pdfDirectory]), but it still doesn't change the directory. What is the right way to use the  '-output-directory' command, because obviously I am not doing it right. pdfDirectory is the directory of the latex file.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the answer, you need to put the option, before the input `tex`. Checkout the update.

Comment: Works perfectly. Cheers!